# Download a folder using CURL in php

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

So I uploaded on server an folder  .zip using curl :

```
function uploadCurs(){
   $ch = curl_init("http://myServer.com/service.php");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CUROPT_POSTFIELDS, "archive = ".NOM_OF_ARCHIVE);
   echo curl_exec($ch);
}
```

Now, how to test if upload with succes and how to download this .zip?
Help me please!!! Thx in advance

Comment: Your question is really unclear what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the file_exists function. [See here for manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

You could do something like this:

```
<?php
    $filename = '/path/to/foo.zip';

    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        echo "The file $filename exists";
    } else {
      echo "The file $filename does not exist";
    }
?>
```